# Error on Installing MySmartUSB Light in linux LMDE 3 Cindy (Makefile: No such file or directory)

Tags: compiling

I need to install MySmartUSB Light in linux LMDE 3 Cindy  as programer for avr in linux,so i downloaded this driver (**Linux_3.x.x_4.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source**) from this [link](https://www.silabs.com/documents/login/software/Linux_3.x.x_4.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source.zip):
based of it's note shown below:

> Last modified July 12, 2019
>
> This bundle contains a modified CP210x driver for the 4.10.0 kernel
>   (Ubuntu 17.04).
>
> It contains:
>
> - Support for the CP2102N
>
> NOTE: This driver is an example of how to perform GPIO operations
>   within the CP210x driver since the driver on kernel.org does not
>   support GPIO at this time. This driver has only been written and
>   tested on the Linux 3.13.0 kernel on Ubuntu 14.04. This driver is a
>   modified version of the existing driver in the Linux 3.13.0 kernel,
>   which is maintained at kernel.org. It is recommened to use the driver
>   there that matches your specific kernel version:
>
> www.kernel.org
>
> Build instrutions:
>
> Ubuntu:
>   1. make ( your cp210x driver )
>   2. cp cp210x.ko to /lib/modules//kernel/drivers/usb/serial
>   3. insmod /lib/modules/

When i want to run `sudo make` in the driver folder i get this error:

```
so@notebook:~/Downloads/Compressed/Linux_3.x.x_4.x.x_VCP_Driver_Source$ sudo make
[sudo] password for so:        
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for so:       
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-9-amd64'
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-9-common/scripts/Makefile.build:44: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-9-common/scripts/basic/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[5]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-9-common/scripts/basic/Makefile'.  Stop.
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-9-common/Makefile:444: recipe for target 'scripts_basic' failed
make[4]: *** [scripts_basic] Error 2
/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-9-common/scripts/Makefile.build:44: /usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-9-common/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[4]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-9-common/arch/x86/entry/syscalls/Makefile'.  Stop.
arch/x86/Makefile:231: recipe for target 'archheaders' failed
make[3]: *** [archheaders] Error 2
Makefile:152: recipe for target 'sub-make' failed
make[2]: *** [sub-make] Error 2
Makefile:8: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.9.0-9-amd64'
Makefile:7: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

SO how could i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you used this system to run make to build drivers before? It's possible you need a few extra packages.

[This guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo) might be somewhat helpful as it describes the necessary steps prior to compiling a software package, although the most important step in your case is probably the first:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
```

Once this is run, try compiling the drivers with `sudo make` again.

If it doesn't work, it's possible you don't have the proper kernel headers. Kernel headers are basically just the C header files for the kernel itself, which is necessary for compilation of things that interface with the kernel (such as the drivers). [Here](https://www.tecmint.com/install-kernel-headers-in-ubuntu-and-debian/) is an installation guide which explains that upgrading/installing the kernel headers is as easy as running:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

Comment: It's work ,thanks a lot.